# .NET error when calling System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsync

Tags: .net, exception, webclient

I am working with the `System.Net.WebClient` class, and I am attempting to upload a file using the UploadFileAsync method.  I am using Visual Studio 2010, and all of my projects are set to use the .NET 4.0 standard runtime, not the client library.

Below is a small section of the code that I am using. About 90% of the time I get the following error:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation' to type 'UploadBitsState'.**

```
Stack Trace:
 at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsyncWriteCallback(Byte[] returnBytes, Exception exception, Object state)
 at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsync(Uri address, String method, String fileName,   Object userToken)
 at FileUpload._StartUpload()
```

The FTP servers I am attempting to upload to are internal to my organization, but one is running IPSwitches WS-FTP and the other is running an IIS 6.0 FTP site, and I have experienced the same issue with both servers.

I have searched high and low for others with a similar problem to no avail.

The actual line that the exception occurs on is the `_Client.UploadFileAsync` method call.

```
private void _StartUpload()
{
    try
    {
        _Client = new WebClient
        {
            Credentials = _Credentials
        };
        _Client.UploadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        _Client.UploadFileCompleted += UploadCompleted;
        _Client.UploadFileAsync(FileBeingUploaded, "STOR", _LocalFile, null);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Methods calls removed for brevity
    }
}

private void UploadCompleted(Object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Methods calls removed for brevity
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Methods calls removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute it synchronously?  Have you tried watching the traffic with a packet sniffer such as `tcpdump` or `WireShark`?

Comment: I have not tried a synchronous call.  As for a sniffer, I have not tried to watch these specific errors, but given that the exception is within the .Net framework and it is a cast issue, I am not sure what the TCP traffic analysis would show.

Comment: Is the file you are uploading `_LocalFile` a static file? In other words, is there **any** possibility of the content of the file being modified/updated while being uploaded? I ask because I can duplicate your error in that particular scenario.

Comment: Sadly no.  private string _LocalFile; private NetworkCredential _Credentials;  That is an interesting observation though, I will look to see if anything could be monkeying with the file name.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of interesting. Looking at the reference source (WebClient.cs), the first line of `UploadFileAsyncWriteCallback` casts the `state` parameter to `UploadBitsState`.

In the method `UploadFileAsync`, there's some exception handling code that reads:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e is ThreadAbortException || e is StackOverflowException || e is OutOfMemoryException)
    { 
        throw; 
    }
    if(fs != null){ 
        fs.Close();
    }
    if (!(e is WebException || e is SecurityException)) {
        e = new WebException(SR.GetString(SR.net_webclient), e); 
    }
    UploadFileAsyncWriteCallback(null, e, asyncOp); 
}
```

`asyncOp` is of type `AsyncOperation`.

It looks like the call to `UploadFileAsyncWriteCallback` here is a bug, because it's passing an object of the wrong type to the callback. The callback does a C-style cast (i.e. `UploadBitsState uploadState = (UploadBitsState)state;`).

But that will only happen if something triggers an exception during the upload.

Is it possible that something in your `ProgressChanged` or `UploadCompleted` event handlers is throwing an exception? Either that or one of the parameters you pass to `UploadFileAsync` is invalid.

**More info**

It really does look like there's a bug in `UploadFileAsync`. For example, the following throws `InvalidCastException`, when according to the documentation it should throw `WebException`.

```
var targetUri = new Uri("ftp://example.com/file.txt");
var srcFile = string.Empty;  // documentation says this will throw WebException
var client = new WebClient();
client.UploadFileAsync(targetUri, "STOR", srcFile, null);
```

I've reported the bug at  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/675575/webclient-uploadfileasync-throws-invalidcastexception

However, from the looks of things I'd say that the reason an exception is being thrown lies in your code. Unfortunately, it's impossible to say *where*, because `UploadFileAsync` is losing the exception information. Perhaps, as somebody else pointed out, trying a synchronous upload will shed more light on the subject.

Comment: Both of the event handler functions start with try { and end with } catch (Exception exception) { // Handle exception } so I do not think they are doing anything inappropriate.  Both your answer and a comment above point to the input parameters causing the issue.  I will have to see if anything unexpected is changing the values.

Comment: @DaleCouch: Sorry, I was referring to the actual data file on the disk drive that you are uploading. If, for example, it was a log file for some other application. If that other application is still running while you are uploading then the other application might append more logging data to the log. This might confuse the Webclient since it started out thinking it was uploading 200 bytes but finds the file is now 250 bytes long. All conjecture on my part though.

Comment: @j.w.r.: Now that seems to make more sense.  That is possible.  All of these files were generated in real-time, and I just closed them before attempting to transmit them.  So it is very possible the OS is catching up.  I will try to change how I go about it and see if that helps.  Thanks for the possible direction.

Comment: @Dale: Can you determine if either of your event handlers is ever called? That would help you narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @Jim: It does not appear so.  The failure is almost immediate.

Comment: @Dale: Have you checked your parameters? Is `FileToBeUploaded` a valid Uri?

Comment: @Dale: See my additional info.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for filing the bug.  I have validated the parameters.  I have also rearranged the code to close the files we are transferring are closed earlier in the process to see if that helps.  In the meantime we have also recreated the functions using BeginRequest and EndRequest using the sample here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse.aspx and we seem to be working now.

Comment: Agreed on the bug.  Try to trap the exception with Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox.